# Tokenize tweet based on Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following example text / tweet:

```
RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is o´o´o´o´o´pen to ‘Talk’ about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment #samsung got:-) heh url_that_cannot_be_posted_on_SO
```

I want to follow the procedure of Table 1 in [Li, T, van Dalen, J, & van Rees, P.J. (Pieter Jan). (2017). More than just noise? Examining the information content of stock microblogs on financial markets. Journal of Information Technology. doi:10.1057/s41265-016-0034-2](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1057/s41265-016-0034-2) in order to clean up the tweet.

They clean the tweet up in such a way that the final result is:

```
 {RT|123456} {USER|56789} {TICKER|AAPL} {NUMBER|2012} notooopen nottalk patent {COMPANY|GOOG} notdefinetli treatment {HASH|samsung} {EMOTICON|POS} haha {URL}
```

I use the following script to tokenize the tweet based on the regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

emoticon_string = r"""
(?:
  [<>]?
  [:;=8]                     # eyes
  [\-o\*\']?                 # optional nose
  [\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\] # mouth      
  |
  [\)\]\(\[dDpP/\:\}\{@\|\\] # mouth
  [\-o\*\']?                 # optional nose
  [:;=8]                     # eyes
  [<>]?
)"""

regex_strings = (
# URL:
r"""http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"""
,
# Twitter username:
r"""(?:@[\w_]+)"""
,
# Hashtags:
r"""(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)"""
,
# Cashtags:
r"""(?:\$+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)"""
,
# Remaining word types:
r"""
(?:[+\-]?\d+[,/.:-]\d+[+\-]?)  # Numbers, including fractions, decimals.
|
(?:[\w_]+)                     # Words without apostrophes or dashes.
|
(?:\.(?:\s*\.){1,})            # Ellipsis dots. 
|
(?:\S)                         # Everything else that isn't whitespace.
"""
)

word_re = re.compile(r"""(%s)""" % "|".join(regex_strings), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)

emoticon_re = re.compile(regex_strings[1], re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)

######################################################################

class Tokenizer:
   def __init__(self, preserve_case=False):
       self.preserve_case = preserve_case

   def tokenize(self, s):
       try:
           s = str(s)
       except UnicodeDecodeError:
           s = str(s).encode('string_escape')
           s = unicode(s)
       # Tokenize:
       words = word_re.findall(s)
       if not self.preserve_case:
           words = map((lambda x: x if emoticon_re.search(x) else x.lower()), words)
       return words

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tok = Tokenizer(preserve_case=False)
    test = ' RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is oooopen to ‘Talk’ about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment #samsung got:-) heh url_that_cannot_be_posted_on_SO'
    tokenized = tok.tokenize(test)
    print("\n".join(tokenized))
```

This yields the following output:

```
rt
@trader
$aapl
2012
is
oooopen 
to
‘
talk
’
about
patents
with
goog
definitely
not
the
treatment
#samsung
got
:-)
heh
url_that_cannot_be_posted_on_SO
```

How can I adjust this script to get:

```
rt
{USER|trader}
{CASHTAG|aapl}
{NUMBER|2012}
is
oooopen 
to
‘
talk
’
about
patents
with
goog
definitely
not
the
treatment
{HASHTAG|samsung}
got
{EMOTICON|:-)}
heh
{URL|url_that_cannot_be_posted_on_SO}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out big time!

Comment: You'll want to use named regex parts (i.e. `(?P<name>..rexex..)` and use `.finditer(..)` to get match objects (which you can call `.groupdict()` on to get a dict of the named groups that matched.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796052/3832970) proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to use *named* capturing groups ([mentioned by thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794025/tokenize-tweet-based-on-regex/54796052#comment96366839_54794025)), and use `groupdict()` to get name-value pairs upon each match. It requires some post-processing though:

- All pairs where the value is `None` must be discarded
- If the `self.preserve_case` is false the value can be turned to lower case at once
- If the group name is *`WORD`*, *`ELLIPSIS`* or *`ELSE`* the values are added to `words` as is
- If the group name is *`HASHTAG`*, *`CASHTAG`*, *`USER`* or *`URL`* the values are added first stripped of `$`, `#` and `@` chars at the start and then added to `words` as `{<GROUP_NAME>|<VALUE>}` item
- All other matches are added to `words` as `{<GROUP_NAME>|<VALUE>}` item.

Note that `\w` matches underscores by default, so `[\w_]` = `\w`. I optimized the patterns a little bit.

Here is a [fixed code snippet](https://ideone.com/hLHDeQ):

```
import re

emoticon_string = r"""
(?P<EMOTICON>
  [<>]?
  [:;=8]                     # eyes
  [-o*']?                    # optional nose
  [][()dDpP/:{}@|\\]         # mouth      
  |
  [][()dDpP/:}{@|\\]         # mouth
  [-o*']?                    # optional nose
  [:;=8]                     # eyes
  [<>]?
)"""

regex_strings = (
# URL:
r"""(?P<URL>https?://(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9_$@.&+!*(),]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+)"""
,
# Twitter username:
r"""(?P<USER>@\w+)"""
,
# Hashtags:
r"""(?P<HASHTAG>\#+\w+[\w'-]*\w+)"""
,
# Cashtags:
r"""(?P<CASHTAG>\$+\w+[\w'-]*\w+)"""
,
# Remaining word types:
r"""
(?P<NUMBER>[+-]?\d+(?:[,/.:-]\d+[+-]?)?)  # Numbers, including fractions, decimals.
|
(?P<WORD>\w+)                     # Words without apostrophes or dashes.
|
(?P<ELLIPSIS>\.(?:\s*\.)+)            # Ellipsis dots. 
|
(?P<ELSE>\S)                         # Everything else that isn't whitespace.
"""
)

word_re = re.compile(r"""({}|{})""".format(emoticon_string, "|".join(regex_strings)), re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)
#print(word_re.pattern)
emoticon_re = re.compile(regex_strings[1], re.VERBOSE | re.I | re.UNICODE)

######################################################################

class Tokenizer:
   def __init__(self, preserve_case=False):
       self.preserve_case = preserve_case

   def tokenize(self, s):
       try:
           s = str(s)
       except UnicodeDecodeError:
           s = str(s).encode('string_escape')
           s = unicode(s)
       # Tokenize:
       words = []
       for x in word_re.finditer(s):
           for key, val in x.groupdict().items():
               if val:
                   if not self.preserve_case:
                       val = val.lower()
                   if key in ['WORD','ELLIPSIS','ELSE']:
                       words.append(val)
                   elif key in ['HASHTAG','CASHTAG','USER','URL']: # Add more here if needed
                       words.append("{{{}|{}}}".format(key, re.sub(r'^[#@$]+', '', val)))
                   else:
                       words.append("{{{}|{}}}".format(key, val))
       return words

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tok = Tokenizer(preserve_case=False)
    test = ' RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is oooopen to ‘Talk’ about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment #samsung got:-) heh http://some.site.here.com'
    tokenized = tok.tokenize(test)
    print("\n".join(tokenized))
```

With `test = ' RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is oooopen to ‘Talk’ about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment #samsung got:-) heh http://some.site.here.com'`, it outputs

```
rt
{USER|trader}
{CASHTAG|aapl}
{NUMBER|2012}
is
oooopen
to
‘
talk
’
about
patents
with
goog
definitely
not
the
treatment
{HASHTAG|samsung}
got
{EMOTICON|:-)}
heh
{URL|http://some.site.here.com}
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/6skhGQ/1/).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, can you show me how to  add "Number" in order to get '{NUMBER|2012}'?

Comment: @HJA24 Added to the `URL`, `CASHTAG` etc., see updated code.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I copied your code and I still get `2012`

Comment: @HJA24 Sorry, wrong fix. The problem was with the `NUMBER` regex pattern, it did not match. I replaced `(?P<NUMBER>[+-]?\d+[,/.:-]\d+[+-]?)` with `(?P<NUMBER>[+-]?\d+(?:[,/.:-]\d+[+-]?)?)`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! If you have time, can you add PERCENTAGE to the script with the following regex `^[+-]? *100(\.0{0,2})? *%?$|^[+-]? *\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? *%?$1`. I got it from http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2325 but I am struggling with how to include it in the script..

Comment: @HJA24 It is a bad regex. It will match the same strings as the NUMBER regex. You may add `| (?P<PERCENTAGE>[+-]? *\d+(?:\.\d+)? *%)` BEFORE the NUMBER alternative.

Comment: I included `,
# Percentage
r"""(?P<PERCENTAGE>[+-]? *\d+(?:\.\d+)? *%)"""
,` immediately after the cashtags-regex but it yiels and error. Btw is it true you create these regex in a little cabin on the hills :-)??

Comment: This is the error: `sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position 446 (line 12, column 169)`

Comment: Ok, add `(?P<PERCENTAGE>[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*%)|` right above `NUMBER` part. See https://regex101.com/r/6skhGQ/3